# Connect to Cosmos using key from Key Vault

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault

I have a Spring Boot application which needs to make use of CosmosDB. My goal is to load the CosmosDB connection key from Key Vault and use that to connect to CosmosDB.
I have placed the key as a secret in Key Vault, but it seems that there is an ordering issue going on, as the Cosmos bean is created before the Key Vault. I am able to connect to successfully connect to Key Vault and have received several keys before this, and I am also able to connect to Cosmos if I hard code the connection key.
Is it possible to load the key from Key Vault and use it to create the Cosmos bean?

What I have tried is the following, but I receive a connection error with Cosmos (due to the key being not set) - probably because it loads before the Key Vault. Is there a robust way to connect to Cosmos or any proper examples available for Spring boot?

Dependencies I am using:

```
azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter (from com.microsoft.azure)
azure-identity (from com.azure)
azure-security-keyvault-secrets (from com.azure)
```

CosmosConfiguration.java class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Profile("!local")
public class CosmosConfiguration extends AbstractCosmosConfiguration {
    @Value("${cosmosPrimaryKey}")
    private String key;

    @Override
    public CosmosClient cosmosClient(CosmosDBConfig config) {
        return CosmosClient
            .builder()
            .endpoint(config.getUri())
            .cosmosKeyCredential(new CosmosKeyCredential(key))
            .consistencyLevel(consistencyLevel.STRONG)
            .build()
    }
}
```

The application.properties (only the relevant parts):

```
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.uri=https://mykeyvault.azure.net
azure.keyvault.secrets-keys=cosmosPrimaryKey

cosmosdb.keyname=cosmosPrimaryKey

azure.cosmosdb.uri=https://mycosmos.documents.azure.com:443
azure.cosmodb.repositories.enabled=true

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea on your case is add judgement when creating 'CosmosClient'. And here's my code.

```
@Autowired
private CosmosProperties properties;

public CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder() {
            DirectConnectionConfig directConnectionConfig = DirectConnectionConfig.getDefaultConfig();
            String uri = properties.getUri();
            if(true) {
                String temp = getConnectUriFromKeyvault();
                properties.setUri(temp);
            }
            return new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(properties.getUri())
                .key(properties.getKey())
                .directMode(directConnectionConfig);
        }

public String getConnectUriFromKeyvault() {
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl("https://vauxxxxen.vault.azure.net/")
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
        KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret("cosmosdbScanWithwrongkey");
        return secret.getValue();
    }
```

CosmosProperties entity:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cosmos")
public class CosmosProperties {

    private String uri;

    private String key;

    private String secondaryKey;

    private boolean queryMetricsEnabled;
    //get set function
    //...
}
```

application.properties:

```
cosmos.uri=https://txxxb.documents.azure.com:443/
cosmos.key=gdvBggxxxxxWA==
cosmos.secondaryKey=wDcxxxfinXg==
dynamic.collection.name=spel-property-collection
# Populate query metrics
cosmos.queryMetricsEnabled=true
```

I followed this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable) to get key vault secret.

Comment: You don't have any other properties in application.properties for example? I thought that these were mandatory by cosmos

Comment: I've added my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for updating it! It's interesting because now the keys are actually hardcoded in the application.properties file. But what if I don't want to hardcode the keys in my properties and fetch them from the keyvault? Would it work if I would still leave the key and secondaryKey hardcoded out?

Comment: @Katie Sure. At first,my program is hardcode keys in properties, and on your case I changed my program. If I delete the key in my properties file, 'properties.getUri()' will get a "" string, then it executes the 'getConnectUriFromKeyvault()' to get the key, and I can use 'properties.setUri()'  to set the key.

Comment: In other words, the code I provided above will execute well no matter I set the value in application.properties, because I'll use the key which getting from key vault to replace the one which is set in properties.